# Best practices with multidimensional arrays: How to specify the axis?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

In numpy, all basic operations can be applied to a specific axis of a given input array, like so:

```python
np.average(an_array,axis=3)
```

in Mathematica however all functions are always applied to the *first* dimension apparently:

```
Dimensions[AnArray]
Dimensions[Mean[AnArray]]
```

> {40, 2, 61, 3}
>
> {2, 61, 3}

When I want to average the third axis I then do:

```
Dimensions[AnArray]
Dimensions[Transpose[Mean[Transpose[AnArray, {3, 2, 1, 4}]], {2, 1, 3}]]
```

> {40, 2, 61, 3}
>
> {40, 2, 3}

This is very cumbersome. Is there an easier way in Mathematica?

Comment: `Map` takes a level specification. E.g. `[Transpose[Mean[Transpose[AnArray, {3, 2, 1, 4}]], {2, 1, 3}]` can be written: `Map[Mean, AnArray, {2}]`

Answer (score 5):

```
SeedRandom[1]
anArray = RandomInteger[10, {40, 2, 61, 3}];

meana = Transpose[Mean[Transpose[anArray, {3, 2, 1, 4}]], {2, 1, 3}];
Dimensions[meana]
{40, 2, 3}

axis = 3;
```

**1.** Map `Mean` at level `axis - 1`:

```
meanb =  Map[Mean, anArray, {axis - 1}]
Dimensions[meanb]
```

> ```
> {40, 2, 3}
> ```

**2.** `Flatten` with `{axis}` as the second argument and take `Mean`:

```
meanc = Mean @ Flatten[anArray, {axis}];
Dimensions[meanc]
```

> ```
> {40, 2, 3}
> ```

```
meana == meanb == meanc
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 2):

For the [`Mean`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean) example, you can use [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total) instead, which does support other dimensions:

```
A = RandomInteger[10, {40, 2, 61, 3}];

r1 = Transpose[Mean[Transpose[A, {3, 2, 1, 4}]], {2, 1, 3}];
r2 = Total[A, {3}]/Dimensions[A][[3]];

r1 === r2
```

> True

Comment: How about other functions? `Norm` e.g.?